# How to insert in an 8-byte integer into MongoDB through JavaScript shell?

Tags: mongodb

As per "MongoDB - The definitive guide",

- JavaScript has only a float type whereas MongoDB has a 4-byte integer, an 8-byte integer and an 8-byte float
- By default all the numbers will be treated as double

When I tried to insert a integer, I am getting the following:

```
> n = {"myInteger" : 3 };    
{ "myInteger" : 3 }    
> db.num.insert(n);
> n = db.num.find();    
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4eeee1e5b593471ba5461577"), "myInteger" : 3 }
```

Based on the above, I have the following questions:

- How do I insert an 8-byte integer into MongoDB through JavaScript?
- How do I check the type of the myInteger value displayed above, by JavaScript?
- How do I check the type of the myInteger value stored in MongoDB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I insert an 8-byte integer into MongoDB through JavaScript?

You can use

```
n = {"myLong" :  new NumberLong("123212313")};
```

Comment: +1 for your other questions, because that seems tricky. You can do `instanceof NumberLong`, but that won't work for 4-byte numbers, they are both just JS "number".

Comment: Thilo:  When I retrieve the value from MongoDB, the data is displayed as 

{"myInteger" : NumberLong(3)}

 as against 

{"myInteger" : {"floatApprox : 3} }

that is given in the book.  Are there two ways of storing 8-byte integers in MongoDB?

Comment: [From mongodb.org]  Prior to version 1.6, the shell will display {"floatApprox": 3} but from 1.6, the shell will display NumberLong(3).